# Get an error in url, when trying to get data from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, openweathermap, urlsession

I'm trying to get data from **openweathermap.org** and get an error in `url`

**Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

This is my data:

```
struct CitiesWeather: Decodable {
    
    var coord : Coordinate?
    
}

struct Coordinate: Decodable {
    
    var longitude: Double
    var latitude: Double
    
}
```

My code:

```
class DayWeatherViewModel: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    let url = "http:// api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=myAppID"
    getData(from: url)

}

func getData(from url: String) {
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in //**<--Error in url!**
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            
            var result: CitiesWeather?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CitiesWeather.self, from: data)
            }
            catch {
                print("failed to convert \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            print(json.coord)
            print(json.coord?.latitude)
            print(json.coord?.longitude)
        }
        
        task.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the URL string. There is a (invalid) space character after `://`. And you should use the `https://` scheme And never print the  `localizedDescription` in a Decoding error block. Print only the `error` instance. It contains the comprehensive decoding error.

Comment: Also, never post your API key on the forum. I edited it out, but I would generate a new key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems here. First your URL string has a space in it between the slashes and the domain `http:// api`. This is not a valid URL

Second, you are force unwrapping the URL object here: `URL(string: url)!` . This is not an issue coming from the API, this is a code issue on your side. Force unwrapping is extremely dangerous and should be avoided at all costs. You can't catch these errors. You need to check for issues first and optionally unwrap the URL. For example:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "...") else {
    print("Failed to parse URL")
    return
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) .....
```